# Format date and time in an array or after array out put to ListBox?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I assume that formatting time and date in an array isn't possible? If yes how would you change the format of a column in a ListBox? This is the part that I'm working with.

```
Private Sub TextBox_Search_Change()
Select Case True
Case OptionButton_User_Name.Value
    temp = UCase(Me.TextBox_Search.Value)
    Dim a()
    Dim rngValues As Variant
    With Sheets("ToolData")
        rngValues = .Range("B2", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Resize(, 11).Value
    End With
    For i = 1 To UBound(rngValues, 1)
        'Check columns B & F for matching values
        If UCase(rngValues(i, 1)) Like "*" & temp & "*" Then
                        '(i, Colunm being searched)
            'Store columns B, F & G for displaying in the ListBox
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve a(1 To 8, 1 To n)
                        'ListBox (Colunms 1-...)
            a(1, n) = rngValues(i, 1)
            a(2, n) = rngValues(i, 2)
            a(3, n) = rngValues(i, 5)
            a(4, n) = rngValues(i, 6)
            a(5, n) = rngValues(i, 7)
            a(6, n) = rngValues(i, 8)
            a(7, n) = rngValues(i, 9)
            a(8, n) = rngValues(i, 10)
        'ListBox = rngValues(B,+Colunms on sheet)
        End If
    Next
    'If anything found, replace the ListBox contents.  Otherwise leave it as it was.
    If n > 0 Then
        Me.ListBox_History.Column = a
        Me.ListBox_History.Column(3, Me.ListBox_History.ListCount - 1) = Format("hh:mm")
    End If

Case Else
```

At the bottom I added this bit as a test `Me.ListBox_History.Column(3, Me.ListBox_History.ListCount - 1) = Format("hh:mm")` But it doesn't format and instead displays `hh:mm` in row 1 of the ListBox.

Comment: It has to be `Format(Me.ListBox_History.Column(3, Me.ListBox_History.ListCount - 1), "hh:mm")` . Not sure if it will work tho.

Comment: Yep I just figured that out and it does work. Now I'm trying to find out how to make it a range instead of a specific row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it should work to format values in an array if they are not numbers.
Try:

```
a(1, n) = Format(rngValues(i, 1), "hh:mm")
```

If this is not working you could cylce trough the column like that:

```
With ListBox1
For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
   .List(i, 0) = (Format(.List(i, 0), "hh:mm"))
Next i
End With
```

Comment: I tried messing around with the array formate some and couldn't get it to work. Looping did the trick though. Thanks for your help.